# Netbeans GUI passing textfield values to action defined in App not in View

Tags: java, model-view-controller, user-interface, netbeans, desktop-application

I created a simple app in Netbeans, it contains a few textfields for user input and a button, I've associated an action with the button through the Netbeans interface but I decided to define the action in the App and not the View so as to follow some notion of MVC.

The action works fine, I can print out the console every time the button is clicked.

But in order to do what I want, I need the values included in the jTextFields!

How to do this? This is the code in TestApp.java:

```
@Action
public void ClickedOnButton() {
    System.out.println("Clicked ok");
    System.out.println("Will now attempt to read notes.ini");

    ReadNotesFile();
}
```

And this is the code in TestView.java:

```
javax.swing.ActionMap actionMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(tpa_fixer.TPA_FixerApp.class).getContext().getActionMap(TPA_FixerView.class, this);
    jButton1.setAction(actionMap.get("ClickedOnButton")); // NOI18N
```

Comment: bind the textField to a property of your app, then access that property in your action

Comment: btw, please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried, and how doesn't it work? The standard way to get a JTextField to display text is to call  `setText()` on it.  Have you tried doing this?

Also,

- Have you gone through the Swing tutorial about these concepts including using text components, JButtons, and ActionListeners?
- Are you seeing any errors in these attempts? If so, post them here.
- Is your "control" class, the one with the listener code, separate from  your "view" or GUI class? If so, does control have a valid reference to view?

**Edit**
You state:

> I don't want to set the text in the jTextFields, I want to get the values out of them and use it in the method that gets run when I click on the button. I can't see how to do this unless I can pass arguments somehow within the body of the action definition in the View class.

What I've done in this situation, where I need to extract information out of gui fields for manipulation in other classes:

- You can give each field an associated public getText() method and then call these methods using the control's reference to the view object. For instance say view has a nameField JTextField, then I'd give it a getNameFieldText() method that returns `nameField.getText();`.
- If you had many such fields, then it may be more efficient to use just one getText method but allow it a parameter to let you choose which field to extract text from. To make this work efficiently, I've sometimes given my GUI a HashMap and then have control pass in the String key that allows the `getText` method to obtain the correct JTextfield, get its text and return it. I often use the same Strings used as JLabels associated with the JTextField as my key Strings.

Comment: Hi mate,
I don't want to set the text in the jTextFields, I want to get the values out of them and use it in the method that gets run when I click on the button.
I can't see how to do this unless I can pass arguments somehow within the body of the action definition in the View class.

Comment: Just added the 2 bits of code in the 2 different classes that deal with the button's action.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate, but answering your 3 question, NO I don't think the control class has a reference to the View class, apart from creating a new View and passing itself into it:

@Override protected void startup() {
        show(new TPA_FixerView(this));
}